# Driving power + USB over cartridge connector

Tags: usb, soldering, 5v

I hack old hardware (mostly microcomputers) by putting new insides in them, but I still consider myself a newbie when it comes to electrical engineering, so please bear with me, because this question might be painfully obvious.

On my next project, I want to put a Raspberry Pi into a dead TI-99/4a computer. I don't want to modify the case, but I would like to use its features. So I am thinking of 3d printing a "cartridge" that would house the pi and a trackball/touchpad and plugging that into the cartridge slot on the TI.

I want to plug in that 3d printed "cartridge" into a matching socket and run a USB and power (5V 2.5A) on the cartridge traces. My plan is to hijack the cartridge and socket by soldering on wires to translate them back into USB and power plug which will run inside the case.

My question is - is that safe? Can I run whatever over a cartridge connector the same way I could run it over a wire?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it's "safe" enough, but the problem will be maintaining adequate signal integrity for the high-speed USB data lines. The impedance requirements are very stringent.

For the power, you'll want to use multiple cartridge contacts for both the +5V and the ground connections.

Where do you plan to route the video? HDMI is another high-speed interface that has strict requirements.

Comment: I was hoping of sneaking in an HDMI via male to female connectors (maybe a mini HDMI if needed) next to the cartridge, My reasoning was that I can get a smaller cartridge connector that would work almost like a guide and when you push it in the hdmi will align and connect. I didn't want to open up an HDMI cable on its own, because I think it would be too complex.

So for the power I should split the cable into multiple contacts on both +5V and ground (like 2-3 carrying +5V and 2-3 for ground?)

Comment: Also, the USB will only run keyboard input through the cartridge, other stuff (usb gamepads for example) would have a port on the cartridge itself.

Comment: Sorry for spamming comments, but more questions arise:
If cartridge port could have a problem with maintaining the signal, is there any other hefty connector I could use? I like the idea of cartridge because it is easy to slide in and out, but maybe some older apparel connectors could work as well? (assuming that the cartridge size/shape would be guiding the connection as well, but with my 3d printing setup I can only get accurate to around 0.3-0.5mm in size)